# Modeling data in MongoDB for a chat application

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to use MongoDB to store chat messages as part of a chat application. The database will be used to display chat history to users joining a channel.

I am trying to determine the best way to model this data in the database. The application is a simple chat app which contains numerous channels that users can chat in. Here are a few options I've considered:

- A `Messages` Collection containing a document for every message. This is easy to implement, however with any significant usage many documents would be created.
- A `Channels` Collection containing a document for every channel. This would result in fewer documents. Messages would be stored as an array on a channel document.

Which of these options is preferred, and why? Is there a better option not listed here?

Answer (score 5):

There are many, many ways to go about modeling something like this. There is no generic "best way," as it really depends on how you plan on using the data, how the app is going to function, etc. However, there are a few things to consider with your approach.

First, having a lot of documents is not an issue. That's what Mongo does - it's great at storing lots of documents. I am a strong advocate of modularity, as it makes things more flexible. I reflect that mindset in my database by separating data as much as possible, and then using references to populate as needed.

This means you have to do more population, but in the end it prevents you from pidgeon holing yourself into having to do things a certain way.

So for your example in particular, a good way would be to combine what you've mentioned above: Have a Messages collection which creates a document for every message. Then have a Channels collection which stores an array of Message IDs (not the message itself).

Why is this useful? I'm assuming you will want to load a Channel, but not all 2,000 messages that are in it. You probably want to load the first 50, and then load more via infinite scroll or something.

This allows you to fetch a Channel document and then populate the first 50 messages. Then you can incrementally fetch 50 more messages at a time if needed.

If you store all of the messages in that array, your Channel document is going to get very, very large.

This also allows a user to edit their Message without editing the Channel document in any way - this is very important!

Having a separate Message schema also allows you to do things like fetch all the messages from a single user. You'll probably want to have a reference in the Message to a User ID.

There is a lot to consider when modeling data like this, but the important things to think about are "How am I going to need to fetch this data?" and "How will I need to modify this data?" Then figure out if your current format makes one of those things difficult.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. One of my concerns was if MongoDB would have issues with storing massive amounts of documents in a single Collection, but as you've suggested this does not appear to be an issue.

Comment: Nope, lots of documents is no concern. It's much better to have a lot of documents than a few really large documents. Large documents mean you HAVE to fetch the whole thing, which means a big payload in your HTTP response (which obviously means long load times). Many small documents is the way to go!